# C++ priority queue in ascending order by specific method for unique pointers to objects

Tags: c++, priority-queue, unique-ptr

I have a class called `Foo` and every `Foo` object has a method called `yVal`. What I wanted was a priority queue of `Foo` objects in ascending order of `Foo.yVal()`

I overloaded the operator> and operator< in `Foo` to this:

```
   bool operator> (const Foo &f){
        return yVal() > f.yVal();
   }

   bool operator< (const Foo &f){
        return yVal() < f.yVal();
   }
```

And So I have the following code:

```
priority_queue<unique_ptr<Foo>, vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>, greater<unique_ptr<Foo>> > Queue;
```

But that was not sorting the priority queue in ascending order of `Foo.yVal()`. Instead it was just sorting them in some unknown random order. I put a cout statement in the operator> and operator< and they weren't even being called. So I tried doing this with a lambda instead:

```
auto cmp = [](Foo left, Foo right) {return left.xVal() > right.xVal();};
priority_queue<unique_ptr<Foo>, vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>, decltype(cmp) > Queue(cmp);
```

But this gave me the error of "non-static data member declared auto" error.

I would ideally like to get this working with the greater<> and operator overloading. If not can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with the lambda (not too familiar with lambdas and would like to avoid them if possible).

I have tried using a functor as well, but again, auto on the functor gives me the same "non-static data member declared auto" error.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, but in the answer I did not understand what that functor was supposed to be used for? sorry, can I have more clarification?

Comment: If you didn't understand an answer, you should ask for clarification in the original question, not post a new one.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you please repost the answer and clarify it. I am new sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got *unknown random order* because when you have `greater<T>`
the following action is performed

```
// pseudocode
cmp(T lhs, T rhs) {
  return lhs > rhs;
}
```

what is `T` in your code? `T` is `unique_ptr<Foo>`, is there `operator>(unique_ptr<>,unique_ptr<>)` in C++ library?
yes, it is [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp), and this operator uses `unique_ptr::get` method while comparing:

```
// Psuedocode when greater used:
cmp (unique_ptr<Foo>& lhs, unique_ptr<Foo>& rhs)
{
  lhs.get () > rhs.get()
}
```

What does `unique_ptr::get` return ? It returns pointer to `Foo`, 
so you are comparing pointers to `Foo` instances. Result is unpredictable.
Code compiles and executes but it does not do what you expected.

---

How to fix your lambda:

What objects are stored in your queue ? `Foo` or `unique_ptr<Foo>` ?
You are storing `unique_ptr<Foo>` so parameters of your lambda should be declared taking this type.

```
auto cmp = [](const unique_ptr<Foo>& left, const unique_ptr<Foo>& right) 
{                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return left->yVal() > right->yVal();
};             ^^
priority_queue<unique_ptr<Foo>, vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>, decltype(cmp) > Queue(cmp);
```

Because instances of `unique_ptr` cannot be copied you have to pass them by reference.
Also use `->` operator to access `yVal` method.

---

EDIT: version with function object.

```
 // comparator as function object with overloaded operator()
 struct Cmp {
   bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& left, const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& right) const {
     return left->xVal() > right->xVal();
   }
 };

class YourClass {
public:
   std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>, Cmp> Queue;
```

Comment: I still get "non-static data member declared auto" error. Can you do this without auto?

Comment: @JoshCarter What compiler are you using ? c++11 is enabled?

Comment: @JoshCarter Where in your code are you creating `cmp` object? As member in class or somewhere in function ?

Comment: As a member in a class, right after the public: keyword

Comment: @JoshCarter Try: `std::function<bool (const std::unique_ptr<Foo>&,const std::unique_ptr<Foo>&)> cmp = ...` if this change didn't help, you should edit your question and show how you define priority_queue and cmp.

Comment: Is there no way to do it with greater<T>